# How to make repeating alarm manager in api level 17?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-7.1-nougat

I've been working on this function for weeks, but i don't know what is wrong with the function. I tested it in the emulator with API level 25 and it work, but when i run it on API level 17, it's not working. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

MainActivity.java

```
private void startAutoSettlement() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

}
```

FirstReceiver.class

```
public class FirstReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, SettlementActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />

<application
    android:name=".core.CoreApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/vidiaprint_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/vidiaprint_logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".receiver.FirstReceiver" />

</application>
```

Thanks

Comment: show us your error or logcat

Comment: there's no error, it just not working

Comment: show us your manifest

Comment: i have added my manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Repeating Alarm Manager

```
public static void startAlarmBroadcastReceiver(Context context) {
    Intent _intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, _intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
 }else{
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
}
```

---

### Alarm Broadcast Receiver

In `AndroidManifest`, just define the class as

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver" >
</receiver>
```

**And code will be like**

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, SettlementActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);

}
}
```

Comment: is it repeat daily? or only once?

Comment: It will be repeated daily